# How to use enumerable with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, enumerable

I have an attribute in my Ignicoes class called "Estado" this attribute is type enumerable. My question is, how I'm going to reference it in javascript?
Here is my model:

```
public enum Estado
{
    Aceite,
    emAvaliacao,
    Recusado
}
public class Ocorrencias
{
   public Estado Estado { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the function on my index that I want to use:

```
    function getData(id) {
    $.get(`/api/IgnicoesAPI/${id}`, function (data) {

        //o div terá que ser limpo para que a informação não seja subreposta
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "";

    
        //adição dos botões que alteram o estado da ignição
        var desativo = "#808080";
        //HERE IS WHERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO ACCESS THE ENUMERABLE
        
            if (data.estado == "aceite") {

          //CODE
        }
        else {

         //CODE
           
            }
        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `enum` and `public` keywords at use in Vanilla Javascript at the moment.

[Source](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)

Note 2 in 11.6.2 at the official Ecma site says:

> enum is not currently used as a keyword in this specification. It is a future reserved word, set aside
> for use as a keyword in future language extensions.
> Similarly, implements, interface, package, private, protected, and public are
> future reserved words in strict mode code.

You can maybe use a workaround like this:

```
var Estado = {
    "Aceite": 0,
    "emAvaliacao": 1,
    "Recusado": 2
}
```

And use it like:

```
var firstEnumValue = Estado.Aceite;
```